# F1 score macro-average

Tags: r, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, f1

In this question I'll differentiate by using lower-case for class-wise scores, e.g. prec, rec, f1, which would be vectors, and the aggregate macro-average Prec, Rec, F1. My formulae below are written mainly from the perspective of R as that's my most used language.

It's been established that the standard macro-average for the F1 score, for a multiclass problem, is not obtained by 2*Prec*Rec/(Prec+Rec) but rather by mean(f1) where f1=2*prec*rec/(prec+rec)-- i.e. you should get class-wise f1 and then take the arithmetic mean.

What I'm wondering is, why is this best? Are there any advantages or drawbacks (or benefits) to using F1 = 2*Prec*Rec/(Prec+Rec) instead?

I was also thinking about using a class-weighted mean , i.e. rather than straight up F1 = mean(f1), which is the unweighted mean, we could weight each value by the class proportion while taking the mean. Any thoughts on the validity, potential benefits/drawbacks of this procedure?

Finally, if (one of) the means are the best procedure for macro-averaging, would you recommend setting f1=0 when prec+rec=0 or is it better to just discount that class altogether by using say `na.rm=TRUE` in R?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471770/multi-class-evaluation-found-different-macro-f1-scores-which-one-to-use). Though I do not yet fully understand it, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03347)<sup>*</sup> performs an in-depth analysis of the difference of the scores.

They shows that 2*Prec*Rec/(Prec+Rec), where Prec and Rec are averages over classes, leads to some issues:

> one formula well 'rewards' classifiers which produce a skewed error type distribution

Apparently the average over class-wise F1 scores does not suffer from this issue. Thus it would be preferable.

---

<sup>*</sup> Opitz, J. and Burst, S., 2019. Macro F1 and Macro F1. arXiv preprint arXiv:1911.03347.

Comment: please add full reference for the paper you cite in case the link dies in the future

Comment: Thanks @Antoine for the remark, I am new to this platform. I have added the reference.

Comment: thank you, +1 !