# Multi-class evaluation: found different macro F1 scores, which one to use?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, multi-class, metric

I want to evaluate my multi-class classifier against a gold reference and obtain a single score that reflects its performance. In my data I have many classes that are important but rare, so I was recommended to use macro F1.

However, I am confused now, since this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03347)<sup>*</sup> shows that two different macro F1 formulas are known and that the scores can differ by 0.5. These are the two formulas:

**1.** average over individual (class-wise) F1 scores

**2.** F1 score over precision and recall averages

*First question*: Do I understand it correctly that they show that it's better to use the **1.** formula over **2.**?

*Second question*: I also do not fully understand if they mean that these scores can differ by 0.5 on a scale [0,100], which would be pretty negligible, or 0.5 on a scale [0,1], which would be kind of extreme.

---

<sup>*</sup> Opitz, J. and Burst, S., 2019. Macro F1 and Macro F1. arXiv preprint arXiv:1911.03347.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having read the paper again in-depth, I found the answers to my questions:

*Answer to first question* Yes, it's (much) better to use the **1.** formula, that is, calculate the **macro F1 as average over class-wise F1 scores**. The other macro F1 formula (harmonic mean over class-wise precision and recall averages) can lead to overly-optimistic scores because it is quite easily biased by specific particularities of the error type distribution. The **1.** formula does not suffer from this issue.

*Answer to second question* Quite surprisingly to me, the maximum difference is 0.5 on a scale [0,1], or, equivalently, 50 on a scale [0,100]. This means that the two macro F1 formulas can lead to **extremely different scores when evaluating classifiers**.